# Past perfect sentence construction

Tags: grammaticality, past-perfect

This is an example sentence demonstrating the usage of past perfect:

> I checked with the supplier and they still hadn't received the contract.

In this case the timeline rule works out as it should. Now, if I modify the sentence a little bit.

> I had just checked with the supplier and they still haven't received the contract.

Is the second sentence grammatically correct? If so, which one of these would one say as verbally pleasant?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your first sentence is indeed grammatical, but the second sentence is not.

If you *had just checked,* that act of checking occurred prior to another past event, and no such other past event is identified in this second sentence.  (Of course, the other past event could be identified earlier in the same text.)  But the use of Present Perfect in the second clause (*haven't received)* is ungrammatical here, because the Present Perfect needs to connect to the present, whereas your second sentence, with its Past Perfect first clause and the implied reference to a later--but still past--time, keeps everything connected in the past, not to the present.

The grammatically correct version of your second sentence would be *I have just checked with the supplier and they still haven't received the contract.*

Your first sentence is focused on the relationship between the 2 events in the past, and my revised version of the second is focused on the connection between the past event in the first clause and the present result/relevance in the second clause.

Comment: Thanks. Now ,the usage makes complete sense to me. Is it right to say " I checked with the supplier and they still haven't received the contract." Does the Present Perfect link to the Present in this case ?

Comment: @user1471: If you leave out the "just" (I can't tell whether that was intentional or unintentional in the question in your comment), "I checked with the supplier and they still haven't received the contract" is fine English, even following strict grammatical rules.

Comment: @StoneyB: I have great difficulty believing even the most extreme pedant could find any reason for saying there's something "not quite right" about *"I just checked and it's still raining"*, for example. On what grounds? How is the construction any different to *"I ate two Big Macs, but I'm still hungry"*? Is that "a venial error" too?

Comment: @StoneyB: I'm still not with it. How does the presence or absence of "just" affect the grammaticality of the tenses? Should I always say *"I have just done it"*, rather than *"I just did it"*?

Comment: @FumbleFingers  Not the grammaticality, but the 'rightness'. It depends on the remoteness of the reference in *checked*. *I checked with the supplier this morning* is one thing; *I checked with the supplier yesterday* another; and *I checked with the supplier last week* quite another. At what point must you shift *have* to *had*?

Comment: UK opticians now check for cataracts in everyone over 50 once every two years. But I won't have to bother about that until next year because mine were just checked four months ago. It depends entirely on the context.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Yes, that's the point I was trying to make; but I'm dropping in on breaks from doing my ——— taxes.

Comment: @StoneyB: haha that's another thing I don't have to bother about until next year, 'cos I just filled in my tax return online last month! Mine was easy (if somewhat depressing), on account of just about everything was £0.00 :(

Comment: @FumbleFingers Mine's in much the same category; but with a wife and a son both in college and both working part-time I have to calculate everything four different ways and see which one is most advantageous.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: there are some other answers on this site saying that in the U.K., if you use "just" or "already" you **must** use a perfect tense. I take it that this is not actually true, just something they [teach](http://learnenglish.britishcouncil.org/en/grammar-reference/just-yet-still-already) in ESL classes.

Comment: @Peter Shor: So now we're not even allowed to say *"I just thought you'd like to know blah blah"*, or *"I already know that!"*, I suppose! (Rules! Who'd have 'em? :)

Comment: ...maybe it's the Indian ESL textbooks making them say *"I am already knowing that!"*

Comment: @PeterShor, there may be quite a few bad ESL teachers out there who teach _already_ in such a simplistic way, but of course it can be used with other tenses besides the perfect.

Answer (score -1):

The first one is what's likely to be said most of the time. The second one is correct, but 'had' puts it into past tense, whereas 'I checked' means it's still present tense.